# Issue with passing parameter from vf page to dynamically created Lightning Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am trying to pass a list of Opportunity records from VF page to a Lightning component but the result in LC is not what is expected. Only the IDs of the records are being retrieved. Below sample of the code.

## Apex Controller

```
public class testClass{

  public List<Opportunity> optyList(){
  List<Opportunity> newList = new List<Opportunity>([SELECT Id, Name, ContractDate 
                                                    FROM Opportunity
                                                    where :<some condition>]);
     return JSON.serialize(newList); 
   }

}
```

## Visualforce page

```
  <apex:page standardcontroller="Opportunity" extensions="testClass">
  <apex:includeLightning />

       <div id="lightning" />

<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:TestApp", function() {
      $Lightning.createComponent("c:TestComp",
      {opties : "{!optyList}"},
      "lightning",
      function(cmp) {
        // do some stuff
      });
    });
</script>
  </apex:page>
```

## TestComp.cmp

```
  <aura:component controller="testClass" >
    <aura:attribute name="opties " type="String"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />

        <aura:iteration var="op" items="{!v.opties }">

        </aura:iteration>
  </aura:component>
```

## TestCompController.js

```
  doInit : function(component, event, helper){
  Console.log('Check-->'+component.get("v.opties")); // Only showing the list of Opty IDs
  }
```

## Console Log

Check--> [0064E000001anbWQAQ, 0064E000001anbVQAQ, 0064E000001anbHYA]

EDIT:
Getting Uncaught Syntax error while trying to pass it as a String

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Lightning component should call that `@AuraEnabled` method directly, using the class as its *own* controller (rather than the Visualforce page's).

Or, your class should return a JSON string that you can then deserialize in Lightning.

What happens now is that when you do this:

```
  $Lightning.createComponent("c:TestComp",
  {opties : "{!optyList}"},
  "lightning",
  function(cmp) {
    // do some stuff
  });
```

the Visualforce runtime flattens the sObject list into the representation that Visualforce uses when it prints out a list as text. That's

> [0064E000001anbWQAQ, 0064E000001anbVQAQ, 0064E000001anbHYA]

As far as Visualforce knows, you've just asked it for some text that gets added into your JavaScript - there's no structured, typed communication between your Visualforce page and Lightning.

So when your Lightning component spins up, what it receives is Visualforce's idea of what it should print out of an sObject list - not JSON, and not objects.

Comment: Yes I understand. But right now, I can't call the method from the Lightning component . So I tried serializing the return value of the method into String type and then pass to LC. But I am getting an 'Uncaught Syntax Error : Unexpected Identifier' error in the browser console. (Image attached to the question)

Comment: You need to use the `JSENCODE()` function in Visualforce to escape all those quotes.